# error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '{' token

Tags: c, compiler-errors

This is the main.

```
int
main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char statement[MAX_LINE];
    int statement_len;
    char type[MAX_LINE];
    char var[MAX_LINE];

    /* Print the output header comment */
    printf(OUTPUT_HEADER, argv[0]);

    /* Loop through statements read on stdin */
    while ((statement_len = next_statement(statement,MAX_LINE)) > 0) {
        printf("%s;\n",statement);
        sscanf(statement,"%s %s",type,var);
        var_lib_check(type,var);
        var_replace(statement,statement_len);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is the function where the error occurs.

```
void
var_replace(char statement, int statement_len){
int i;
int x;

for (i = 0; i < statement_len; i++){
    for (x = 0; x < num_of_var; x++){
        if (strcmp(var_library[x],statement[i]) == 0){
            printf("hello");
        }
    }
}
return;
}
```

The error:

> expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '**attribute**' before '{' token

How do I fix this?

Comment: To which line does the compiler point? We're not GCCs or clangs, you know

Comment: The error is probably before that function, you probably don't have matching braces.

Comment: statement is a char variable while you treat it an array of char in the `strcmp()` line.

Comment: You should worry about other things for now, like passing a `char` and using an index on it. There is no string type in c, and `char != string`.

Comment: @mfro That's indeed an error, but it won't cause that message.

Comment: @zkvsl , can you please specify what that function is supposed to do.

Comment: Does your real code also miss all `#include`s?

Comment: Both functions are correct. The error must be somewhere else, e.g. in your header file.

Comment: I fixed it as I forgot the #include and i changed the array pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is

```
void var_replace(char statement, int statement_len){
```

So, it expects a character as 1st argument. But what you pass is a string

```
char statement[MAX_LINE];
var_replace(statement,statement_len);
               ^
              statement is a character array
```

That is one problem. Then in your function, you use

```
if (strcmp(var_library[x],statement[i]) == 0){
                                    ^
                                  but statement is a character, not a string
```

If you want to check each character, then don't use `strcmp()`

Comment: And how does this answer the question?